# one_time_keyboard doesn't work

Tags: php, node.js, bots, telegram-bot

Looks like one_time_keyboard option for telegram bots doesn't work at all.

```
var opts = {
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        one_time_keyboard:true,
        keyboard: [
          ['Yes, you are the bot of my life ❤'],
          ['No, sorry there is another one...']]
      })
    };
      bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'test',opts);
```

Tried in php and node.js. Nothing works. Does anybody else experiencing the same problem or it's just my case?

Comment: One time keyboard have strange behavior. What do you means with “doesn't work at all”?

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#replykeyboardmarkupone_time_keyboard Boolean  Optional. Requests clients to hide the keyboard as soon as it's been used. Defaults to false. As said by telegram api docs it should hide itself after typed a message but doesn't happen. At least on my android device and on my pc desktop

Comment: keyboard doesn't hide on first usage

Comment: On my own experience one_time_keyboard have different behavior on different os/devices. Try also on web client. Your JSON seems fine to me.

Comment: no way. web client and adroid/lollipop devices fail to hide on first usage. can you address me to a succesfull bot using one_time_keyboard?

Comment: Frankly, not. I should by find, subscribe it, test... I have used it, but I abandoned it.